# Is Array.prototype originally created by Object Constructor Fn & later had its constructor set back to Array?

Tags: javascript, oop, inheritance, constructor, prototype

The reason I asked this question is because:

```
Function.prototype.constructor === Function
typeof Function.prototype === "function"
```

From the following three lines, I would assume `Array.prototype` is created by Object Constructor:

```
typeof Array.prototype === "object"   
Array.prototype instanceof === Object
Array.prototype.__proto__ === Object.prototype
```

However why is the following **not** equal to Object?

```
Array.prototype.constructor === Array
```

So I can only assume it is `Array.prototype` is created by Object Constructor first, then had its prototype constructor set back to Array?

If this is the case, is there a reason behind doing so? or if not, how does it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Func.prototype.constructor` always references `Func`, i.e. the function of which `Func.prototype` is the prototype object of.

It think you are making the following conclusion: Since

```
typeof Function.prototype === "function"
// and 
Function.prototype.constructor === Function
```

it must be that

```
typeof Array.prototype === "object"
// and
Array.prototype.constructor === Object
```

But this conclusion is wrong. Everything in JavaScript is an object, apart from primitive values. Functions are objects as well, but they are special types of objects because they implement the internal `[[Call]]` property. And since all functions must have this internal method implemented, it makes sense that `Function.prototype` implements it.

[Here is how the `typeof` operator works:](http://es5.github.io/#x11.4.3)

> 3. Return a String determined by Type(val) according to Table 20.

This table shows:

> Type of val                                                                
>   Result
>
> Object (native and does not implement [[Call]])
>         
>   "object"
>   Object (native or host and does implement [[Call]])
>     "function"

Comment: Thank you. I think I got the typeof pretty clear now. The main question still, is what determines a constructor value of a prototype , for example: Array.prototype.constructor === Array, is it always going to be the Constructor function itself?

Comment: Yes. When I will be back at a computer, I will provide a link.

Comment: Wow, this is what I have been wrapping my head around for - how the code itself works behind the scene. Kinda "index" of "Javascript Index". Thank you so much Felix.

Answer (score 0):

From MDN (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/constructor):

"Returns a reference to the Object function that created the instance's prototype. " so constructor is the function used to construct the object.